# Scrollbar width is not not decreasing

Tags: css

I am using overflow:auto setting and its implementing scrollbar but I am not able to control the width of scrollbar. Its breadth is too big.
I used webkit-scrollbar property(width: 0.5em;) but even that is not working in IE.
Please suggest, how can I decrease its width and make it look better.

IE9 I am using.

Comment: Which version of IE ?

Comment: I don't think you can control the scrollbar width in IE. the -webkit-property means it will only work on webkit browsers, like chrome or safari. If you really want to change the appearance of the browser you'll have to use javascript

Comment: This should work, i remember i used it and it worked fine -> http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/ . I don't know about the width, tho

Comment: @Nick there are only color property, not width

Comment: @Nick - Yes, I can only see color property and nothing for width.Thanks for help but please suggest if you have any property for width too.

Answer (score 0):

- http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

```css
body{
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```